# Mini DisplayPort to USB Type C

Tags: monitors, usb-c, cable

How do I get excellent quality video output from Surface Pro 6 (Mini DisplayPort) to Dell (S2722DC QHD 1440p 75 Hz) USB-C monitor?

I’ve used mini DisplayPort adapter to HDMI cable then connected to the monitor using HDMI 1.4 but quality is a bit blurry.

Most of items in market is for USB-C to Mini DisplayPort but not the other way around.

Comment: You should go back to the original idea of MiniDP to HDMI and figure out *why* it "is bit blurry". HDMI, USB-C, and DisplayPort are all just different connectors transmitting very similar digital signals. If the quality looked bad it's probably the display itself or the settings you were using. HDMI 1.4 can support 2560x1440 75 Hz with 4:4:4 chroma so using a different adapter that works through DisplayPort isn't going to provide "better quality".

Comment: Also, *what* was blurry? Did you run the ClearType tuning utility to make sure that Windows was rendering text properly for your display? This makes a huge difference on how sharp text looks.

Comment: I tried setting recommended resolutions, scaling, cleartype but. Text on bigger screen still bit blurry to me. I am using one adapter and a cable to connect these two, instead of using one cable - could it be an issue? Surface pro 6 has really clear resolution but not on my dell monitor.

Comment: I also mentioned it could just be the monitor itself. That Dell 27" screen has a PPI (pixels per inch) of 108, and the Surface Pro 6 has a PPI of 267. That's a 247% sharper screen! Maybe it looks blurry because you have such a high pixel density to compare it against. (The Surface has something like "retina" and the big screen doesn't.) Take a photo of the blurry screen and add it to your question if you don't think this is what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but here's a huge list of [Bi-directional DisplayPort->USB-C, HDMI->USB-C, and HDMI->DP cables](https://dancharblog.wordpress.com/2020/05/10/bi-directional-usbc-dp-cables).

You are probably best served by converting the mini DP to full size DisplayPort first by using a cheap passive adapter and then use a bidirectional cable/adapter like the DeLock 63928 or AmazonBasics UTC-DP-B-L or MonoPrice 139240. You could, of course, use the Wacom Link Plus that's sort of the "joker" solution to all of these "legacy video to USB C monitor" problems but it costs multiple times these simple adapters.